# How to select a checkbox from JS

Tags: javascript

I have this DOM structure

```
<div id="__item13-__xmlview1--UploadCollection-0-cli-selectMulti-CbBg" class="sapMCbBg sapMCbHoverable sapMCbActiveStateOff sapMCbMark">
    <input id="__item13-__xmlview1--UploadCollection-0-cli-selectMulti-CB" type="CheckBox">
</div>
```

The input element is a checkbox. I am trying this:

```
document.getElementById("__item13-__xmlview1--UploadCollection-0-cli-selectMulti-CB").click();
```

But it is not able to select the checkbox.

Comment: this works. make sure you javascript runs after your DOM has been parsed.

for example include the script at the end of the body tag or run the code on DOMContentLoaded https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
document.getElementById("__item13-__xmlview1--UploadCollection-0-cli-selectMulti-CB").checked = true;
```